# Custom Json Converter With Constructor Arguments

Tags: json, dependency-injection, converters, autofac

I am trying to create a custom Json converter that has no default constructor and instead takes a factory that is dependency injected by Autofac. When ever I hit the object that uses this converter I get an exception that there is no no-arg constructor to use for the deserialization.

I have an  objects and primitives. One of the objects is an abstract base object that I have the converter on. Since this converter is abstract I want to dependency inject a factory into the converter's ReadJson method to make the choice as to what conversion to make.

Currently the code is something like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Autofac;

using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

using Newtonsoft = Newtonsoft.Json;

public class JsonModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<SubThingFactory>()
            .As<IFactory>()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => this.CreateJsonSerializerSettings(c)).SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver>()
            .As<IContractResolver>()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<IsoDateTimeConverter>()
            .As<Newtonsoft.JsonConverter>()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<SubThingConverter>()
            .As<Newtonsoft.JsonConverter>()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => new StringEnumConverter
        {
            CamelCaseText = true
        })
            .As<Newtonsoft.JsonConverter>()
            .SingleInstance();
    }

    private Newtonsoft.JsonSerializerSettings CreateJsonSerializerSettings(IComponentContext context)
    {
        var settings = new Newtonsoft.JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
            NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
        };

        settings.ContractResolver = context.Resolve<IContractResolver>();

        foreach (var converter in context.Resolve<IEnumerable<Newtonsoft.JsonConverter>>())
        {
            settings.Converters.Add(converter);
        }

        return settings;
    }
}

public class ThingBeingDeserialized
{
    private string Name;
    private SubThing subby;
}

[Newtonsoft.JsonConverterAttribute(typeof(SubThingConverter))]
public abstract class SubThing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        //Uses reflection to get the name from a custom attribute
        return this.Name;
    }
}

[CustomName("A")]
public class SubThingA : SubThing
{
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
}

[CustomName("B")]
public class SubThingB : SubThing
{
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}

public class SubThingConverter : Newtonsoft.JsonConverter
{
    //This is Autofac injected in
    private readonly IFactory factory;

    public SubThingConverter(IFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == Newtonsoft.JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        var type = jsonObject["type"].ToString();

        return this.factory.GetSubThing(type, jsonObject);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(Newtonsoft.JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var type = value.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        var jObject = new JObject
        {
            { "type", type.Name }
        };

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            if (prop.CanRead)
            {
                var propVal = prop.GetValue(value, null);
                if (propVal != null)
                {
                    jObject.Add(prop.Name, JToken.FromObject(propVal, serializer));
                }
            }
        }

        jObject.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(SubThing);
    }
}

public interface IFactory
{
    SubThing GetSubThing(string type, JObject restOfObj);
}

public class SubThingFactory : IFactory
{
    public SubThing GetSubThing(string type, JObject restOfObj)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "A":
                return new SubThingA
                {
                    Field1 = (int)(restOfObj["Field1"])
                };
            case "B":
                return new SubThingB
                {
                    Field2 = (string)(restOfObj["Field2"])
                };
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class CustomNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CustomNameAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The way I am doing the Autofac injection for the JsonSerializerSettings is by registering the settings such that the settings.Converters will pick up the enumeration of all the JsonConverters that are registered with the Autofac container and the SubThingConverter is registered such that when it is resolved it will have the IFactory resolved for it and the JsonSerializer also comes from the autofac container with these settings.

Even when I skip the dependency injection and use a new JsonSerializer with the JsonSerializerSettings with the custom converter added as

```
settings.Converters.Add(new SubThingConverter(new SubThingFactory()))
```

I still get the complaint that the SubThingConverter does not have a no arg constructor.

It seems to me that overridding the settings to explicitly use this converter should be enough. I also tried adding in the object[] params in the JsonConverter attribute on the SubThing, I couldn't get it to work and it seems to need to be a compile time array, which doesn't work with the dependency injection I need to do. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: JordanSchiller your code is absolutely not compilable. I suppose `SubThingA` and `SubThingB` should inherit `SubThing`. Method `WriteJson` in [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm) is void and does not return any value. In the `factory`, you try to set the `Field1` prop into `SubThingB` instance. That prop does not belong to that type. Is there any question related to Autofac?

Comment: I updated the code to compile